# Como configurar o editor Summernote para exibir uma pagina web dentro da janela?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

Bom dia, queria uma pequena ajuda e dicas para fazer o editor de texto summernote abrir uma pagina web, por exemplo em uma pagina eu estou digitando o HTML normalmente e com clico para ver o codigo, iria aparece a pagina pronta.

exemplo:

[image: quando estou digitando um codigo HTML]

[image: E quando clicar para visualizar a pagina]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o html criado no SummerNote dessa forma:

```
var htmlPagina = $('#idDoEditor').summernote('code');
```

Crie uma div onde você quer colocar o resultado:

```
<div id="htmlGerado"></div>
```

E com jquery jogue o html do summernote nele:

```
$('#htmlGerado').html(htmlPagina);
```